# How to hide a tab from the tabbar on React Native Navigation V5?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

[IMG : What I want to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R7Ep.png)

```
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2'}}
        initialRouteName="Catalog">
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Settings"
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Alterações',
            title: 'Configurações',
            tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cog" color="#000" size={22} />
            ),
          }}>
          {(props) => (
            <Settings
              {...props}
              params={{
                cpf: params.cpf ? params.cpf : cpf,
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Tab.Screen>

        <Tab.Screen
          name="Catalog"
          options={{
            tabBarVisible: false,
            title: 'Ofertas',
          }}>
          {(props) => (
            <Catalog
              {...props}
              params={{
                pracaId: params.pracaId ? params.pracaId : pracaId,
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Tab.Screen>
           [...]
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
```

Forgive me for opening this issue. But I googled it a lot and didn't find a solution that would solve my problem.
I just want to hide that tab everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my solution was work inside react-native-apper

/node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/BottomNavigation.tsx

```
renderTouchable = (props: TouchableProps) => {
 if(props.route?.name !== "Catalog")
   return <Touchable {...props} />
}
```

I don't know if it's a good practice, but I need it and the react-navigation maintainer don't help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this option `tabBarVisible` to hide a tab inside a Tabbar

```
<Tab.Screen
      name="Ofertas"
      options={{
        //.......
        tabBarVisible: false
}}>
```

Comment: looks like this option does'nt exists. I already put it and still appers in the tab bar